# Loading and unloading "chunks" of tiles in a 2d tile engine with 2d camera

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0, tiles

I am making a 2d tile based game in C# and XNA 4.0. I am having trouble loading and unloading "chunks" of tiles(blocks). The whole world is randomly generated and is infinate on both axis. How would I go about loading and unloading chunks of tile data in the camera's view?

A pastebin to the pastebin links(I still have the 2 link cap):

http://pastebin.com/9PYr8cvC

Comment: World class:
http://pastebin.com/K9Qfzh2z

Chunk class:
http://pastebin.com/sCknxzig

Camera class:
http://pastebin.com/JMueU0HN

Player class:
http://pastebin.com/tm4kUQUb

Comment: There's probably not enough info you gave there. Unless XNA actually has that pre-built, people don't know how you make chunks and so on.

Comment: @Bane In World.cs there is a method called GetChunk(ChunkLocation location), And a *Location is a Vector2 with custom helper methods. Generator.cs:
http://pastebin.com/PkrnZteN

Comment: I get the picture, but know that I never worked with XNA. :)

Comment: Kinda of already had this question here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Basically you want to have a range around your camera. When chunks come into this range, you load/generate them. When chunks leave this range, you save/unload. Keep in mind you'll want to keep the loaded range larger than the visible range, so your chunk loading isn't seen.

At the moment it looks like you're storing your chunks in a dictionary. That's kind of a strange choice, and it may be a little more work for you to maintain your chunks with that data structure.

It looks like you've got a lot of the functions you need already, nice work. You'll want a list of chunk positions that should be loaded, your loaded list. Your update loop is going to maintain that list. As the camera moves, you update the list to include all the chunks in the range of the camera.

This is where the dictionary choice is a little strange. Essentially you'd have to loop through all your dictionary entries, unload the chunks that aren't in your loaded list and load the ones that aren't in your dictionary but are in your loaded list. The alternative is to have some sort of linked list structure. Where you can add/remove chunks from either end. This does get a little tricky when dealing with 2D linked lists, but I think you can make it work.

It would look something like this:

Starting with this scenario, where the red dot is the camera, moving in the X plus direction. All the grid squares (chunks) touching the green area are currently loaded.

[image]

Then the camera moves far enough to get some new chunks:

[image]

All the blue chunks will be loaded/generated. All the red chunks will be unloaded/saved.

As for maintaining the list, you can update whenever the camera moves past a chunk boundary. Like if it moves past the X plus boundary of the chunk it's currently over, like in the example above, the chunks to be added or removed from the list could be found like this:

```
for(int y = Camera.Position.Y + LoadRange.Y; y >= Camera.Position.Y - LoadRange.Y; y--){
    AddToLoadedList(GetChunkRootPositionAt(Camera.Position.X + LoadRange.X, y));
    RemoveFromLoadedList(GetChunkRootPositionAt(Camera.Position.X - LoadRange.X, y));
}
```

Where `GetChunkRootPositionAt` converts a world position into the root position of the chunk that contains that location. And the `LoadedList` functions take a Vector2 to add/remove from the loaded list.

Finally, you may find adding in a buffer for unloading could be nice. If someone is moving the camera around a lot right on a chunk boundary, you can save a lot of loading/unloading by just keeping it loaded. Essentially, you may find that unloading at the same time as loading isn't necessarily the best option.

Comment: why not use a dictionary with the x,y (and z if you're that way inclined) coords as your key? like:
{'0:0': chunk0, '1024:0':chunk1}

Comment: Arrays have a faster look up time, use less memory as there is no hash, and are contiguous so their faster to iterate through should that ever be necessary.

Comment: Also I wouldn't suggest a 2d linked list I would suggest a graph via an adjacency list. That way finding the next chunk would only take looking at the 4 or 8 adjacent chunks and if there isn't one in the desired location you can generate it then and add it to your graph.

Comment: That's close to how the dictionary is currently being used. But the key is `ChunkLocation`, which I'm sure at least has the x,y(z). The reason for the linked list (or similar structure) is it's easier to keep track of where things are. For example, it's harder to iterate through all the chunks on the X-minus side of the world with a dictionary, since you'd first have to look through the entire dictionary to find all the chunks there. I think it'll save headaches in the future, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: `graph via an adjacency list`. Agree.

Comment: Thanks for the help but looking at adjacency lists is making my head spin! Any examples on that @ClassicThunder or @Byte56?

Comment: Try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379574(v=vs.80).aspx down where it says "Representing a Graph Using an Adjacency List" for a visual representation. Not the clearest of explanations but I can't seem to find a non mathematical explanation.  :/

Comment: But its basically just a list of chunks touching the current one. So all you need is an array of size 8. So assuming 0 is the top left, 1 is the top, 2 is the top right, and three is the right touching chunk. When your camera leaves the current chunk on the right you can do AdjacencyArray[3] and get the tiles to draw. If AdjacencyArray[3] is null create a new chunk, and have AdjacencyArray[7] the left side of the new chunk point to the current chunk.

Comment: I'd post another question about implementing an adjacency list, rather then go into discussion here in the comments.

Comment: @Byte56 Would changing my chunk dictionary to a 2d array of a predetermined size for loaded chunks make this any easier?

Comment: You're asking if moving to a fixed size would be easier. Easier yes, better maybe. The dictionary is nice because of it's flexibility, an array is nice because of it's usability and predictability. A linked list or adjacency list kind of gives you the best of both worlds in this situation.

Comment: @Byte56 I posted another question about storing my chunks if you are interested because you seem very knowledgeable about that topic.

http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25105/how-to-store-chunks-of-tiles-or-how-to-make-my-implementation-work

Comment: I'm not too keen on graph theory, but wouldn't an adjacency list be non-spatial? eg, the chunk would know that it *has* neighbours, but not *where* they are

Comment: @Danjen In this case, since we're talking about a regular grid, the adjacency list would likely also contain information about direction. It's not strictly like a typical graph theory adjacency list.

Answer (score 1):

Find out how large your screen is and only render tiles that fall within that range. You might need a camera object to keep track of this data and some sort of x & y offset variables to keep track of movement around the world.

```
if(tile is inside of the window)
    render;
```

Comment: I understand that concept but, but I don't understand how to:

A. Get center of the camera

B. Check the camera window vs the viewport window